# Tennis Deuce probability to win

Tags: probability

Suppose you're at a "deuce" in the game of tennis.  This means that to win the match, you need to be two points ahead of the other player (i.e. you need to score two points in a row).

The probability that you win a point at any given time is 0.25.  What is the probability that you win the match?

--
Find the error in the following solution:

Let p be the probability that we win the match.  Then we can write:
$ p = 0.25\cdot[0.25 + 0.75\cdot p] + 0.75\cdot [0.25\cdot p + 0.75\cdot 0]$
p = 1/10  (this is incorrect, correct answer is 1/12)

Comment: Hm.. what have you tried?

Comment: Your formula looks correct.  How do you get 1/12 ?

Comment: @JasonKim Can do this using infinite series:
$p^2 + 2(1-p)p*p^2 + [2(1-p)p]^2*p^2 + ...$
and will get 1/12 which should be the right answer.  Why doesn't mine work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is fine.  You arithmetic is off.

$p=0.25[0.25+0.75\cdot p]+0.75[0.25\cdot p+0.75\cdot 0]$

multiply it out:

$p = 0.0625 + 0.375 p\\
0.625 p = 0.0625\\
p = 0.1$

infinite series approach

$p = (\frac 14)^2\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty (2\cdot \frac 14\cdot \frac 34)^n\\
\dfrac {\frac 1{16}}{1-\frac {6}{16}} = \frac 1{10}$

Comment: Thank you.  Spent about two hours wondering if I teleported to a different universe when I couldn't figure this out